# DIV not showing up in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I just made a very simple website, but I have run into a problem. In Firefox and Safari, I can see the DIV with id #sponsors, but in Chrome it is gone. I am on a mac.

Anyone have a solution?

http://www.tweetup.vn/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is set to:

```
visibility: hidden !important;
display: none !important;
```

in my Chrome and it is my [Ad blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) that does it.

Change the Id to something less ad-ish.

Comment: *Right-click -> Inspect element* is your friend :)

Comment: Came across the same issue.. Great answer!