# Div does not show in Google chrome (shows in firefox)

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm new to programming  and tried building a page with CSS/HTML using flex. I've made a panel of 3 divs that would stretch across a page to display various ads. I've only completed one so far, but when testing in chrome it does not seem to work. I"ve also tested in firefox which seems to work fine. I've tried clearfixes to no avail.

**Scss:**

```
  main{
    width:80%;
    margin: calculateRem(30pt) auto;

    &>*{
      width:100%;
    }

    #featured_ad_panel{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      margin-top: calculateRem(30pt);

      &>figure{
        flex-grow: 1;

        #ad_container{
          height:270px;
          width: 217px;
          border: calculateRem(1pt) solid $color-4;
          margin: auto;

        }

      }
    }
  }
```

**Html**

```
<main>
   <section id="featured_ads">
      <h1>Featured Deals</h1>
      <section id="featured_ad_panel">
         <figure id="ad1">
            <div id="ad_container">
               <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/217x270" alt="Phone Image">
            </div>
         </figure>
         <figure id="ad2">Ad 2</figure>
         <figure id="ad3">Ad 3</figure>
      </section>
   </section>
   Scss:
   <section id="bargains"></section>
</main>
```

**Note** the calculateRem function is a simple func that I made to get the Rem sizes from points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a question from a long while back, but may be helpful to you. Try turning off your adblocker in Chrome or changing the id's to something "less ad-ish" (according to the answer on the other question)

Other stackoverflow question: [DIV not showing up in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512919/div-not-showing-up-in-chrome)

Comment: You sir are my hero. Thanks

Comment: You're very welcome :]